# GCP Firestore Python API PermissionDenied error with a service account

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

My goal is to make use of GCP's Firestore Python 3 API. I have created a service account and followed the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/quickstart-servers) for the setup. However, any request to Firestore still results in `google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Missing or insufficient permissions` error. I made sure that Firestore database rules allow all reads & writes in Firebase console. I have added both `Owner` & `Cloud Datastore Owner` roles to my service account, but to no avail. I have tried providing credentials in 2 ways, neither of which has proven to be successful:

```py
from google.cloud import firestore

# Method #1
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = os.getcwd() + "/credentials.json"
db = firestore.Client()

# Method #2
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials
db = firestore.Client(project="my-project-id",
                      credentials=Credentials.from_service_account_file("credentials.json"))
```

I have run out of options and would appreciate any help with this problem.

Comment: 1) Set the environment variable before running the program, not inside. 2) This statement is overwriding your previous settings: `Credentials.from_service_account_file("credentials.json")` Specify the full path to the credentials file.

Comment: For development, you will want to setup ADC (Application Default Credentials) and not store references to the credentials or manipulate the environment variables in your program. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials/

Comment: @JohnHanley, thanks for the suggestions, but it turns out I did not specify the most important part of my issue, which is that I was running this code in a GCP CE VM. My bad. But funny enough, on the VM I don't even have to specify any credentials, it just somehow works. Perhaps VM automatically configures application default credentials on setup?

Comment: Yes the VM grabs credentials from the Metadata Server. My articles explain this in more detail. Research Compute Engine service accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it matters where you execute this code. I was executing it in the GCP's Compute Engine VM instance and apparently one has to enable the corresponding cloud service in the VM's Cloud API access scopes. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53794300/3805929) answer in particular has resolved my issue.